# How to create MobileFirst analytics log in native Android app?

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I'm trying to write custom analytics log in native Android app. I don't see it in Analytics console. What could be wrong?
I use following code:

```
    public void logEvent(View view) {

    WLAnalytics.enable();

    String json = "{\"package\": \"mfpStart\" }";
    try {
        WLAnalytics.log("Custom event", new JSONObject(json));

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    WLAnalytics.send();
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make sure you are calling `WLAnalytics.setContext(context)` for example on your Activity's onCreate method do something like.

```
class YourActivity extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        // other code
        WLAnalytics.setContext(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you help me one thing, Do we need to set the context in every activity or only once is fine?